# Second Node App Deploy on Heroku always Fails

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, deployment

Im experiencing a weird issue with Heroku when deploying.

My second deploy (after committing new github changes and pushing them to my app) always seems to crash with the same error message, however, if I create a new Heroku app and deploy it there, it will always deploy successfully.

This is the error that I receive when the build fails.

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 8.x...
       Downloading and installing node 8.9.4...
       Using default npm version: 5.6.0
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
       npm ERR! path /tmp/build_ab6facc2006ab24a04683a1ab7266974/bothello-Bothello-Faq-v2-Demo-e5f231b/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist
       npm ERR! code ENOENT
       npm ERR! errno -2
       npm ERR! syscall rename
       npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/tmp/build_ab6facc2006ab24a04683a1ab7266974/bothello-Bothello-Faq-v2-Demo-e5f231b/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist' -> '/tmp/build_ab6facc2006ab24a04683a1ab7266974/bothello-Bothello-Faq-v2-Demo-e5f231b/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/.minimist.DELETE'
       npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
       npm ERR! enoent

       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-01-06T05_06_42_422Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       Some possible problems:

       - Node version not specified in package.json
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Im a bit stuck here on what to do. Any help would be great.

Cheers,
J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To anyone interested, I fixed this by disabling the Node Modules Cache via the Heroku CLI:

```
heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false --app app_name
```

This has fixed the build issue.